# complexity of program having two outer for loop running n times and one for loop running 4 times inside.second for loop

Tags: algorithm

```
for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++)
{
    for($k=1;$k<=4;$k++)
    {
        # o(1) operation
    }
}
```

for this what i have find out is this will be O(n) times as the constant for loop will run 4n times.

So in this case will it follow the same logic , as it has got one extra for loop , means inside will run 4n times + outer loop:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++)
    {
        for($k=1;$k<=4;$k++)
        {
            #o(1) operation
        }
    }
}
```

will it be O(n^2) or O(n^2)+O(4)??

Comment: it should be O(4*n*n) and that's ~ O(n*n)

Comment: `O(n^2) + O(4)` is the same as `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 4):

It's O(N<sup>2</sup>). Since 4 is a constant that is independent of `N`, it does not change the result of big-O.

Of course the third nested loop does make the program run slower. However, since the slowdown is by a constant factor, the asymptotic timing of the program expressed in big-O notation does not change.

Answer (score 4):

Let's break it down:

- Outer loop - n iterations

  - 1st inner loop - n iterations

    - 2nd inner loop - 4 iterations

      - Loop action - O(1)

This totals in `O(n*n*4*1) = O(4*n^2) = O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

try to make yourself clear about the logic of using '+' or '*'

//code 1

```
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++)
{
    for($k=1;$k<=4;$k++)
    {
        #o(1) operation
    }
}
}
```

this is O(4*n*n)~O(n*n)

//code 2

```
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++)
{
        #o(1) operation
}
}

 for($k=1;$k<=4;$k++)
    {
        #o(1) operation
    }
```

while this is O(n*n) + O(4) ~ O(n*n)

Hope you got the difference

Comment: Please put comments and reason if you are down voting this. There is no point in down voting without any comment

Comment: Expressions like O(4*n*n) can be simplified to O(n*n). Moreover, using this kind of notation can be confusing(because it might look like O(3*n*n) and O(4*n*n) are different things, but they both are O(n*n)).

Comment: I had already mentioned in the comments section that O(4*n*n)~O(n*n)

Comment: In fact i was the first one to comment the answer of the asked question

Comment: O(n*n) + O(4) is also confusing because it is O(n*n).

Comment: @Prashant, first one to comment the answer, but you never actually wrote an answer. Why?

Comment: @Samuel But my answer is here, at that time i was thinking of the explanation